# Not able to display static images and css files

Tags: python, django

I want to display static images and CSS file

settings.py

```
    STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = ( BASE_DIR +"/articles/static",)
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static",)
```

In Template I am trying display the images from img folder

article.html

```
     {% load staticfiles %}
     <img src = "{% static '/img/default-by.gif' %}" alt = "left slide"/>
```

Folder Structure

The folder structure where I have tried to access static images according to the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/
    Folder Structure

```
NewsArticles
 -->articles
   --> static
      -->articles
          -->img
            -->default-by.gif

db.sqlite3 
manage.py
media
NewsArticles
README.md
static
templates
```

I am using firebug to check the image location its showing as mentioned http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/default-by.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving wrong path for your image. It should be like this

```
{% load staticfiles %}
 <img src = "{% static 'articles/img/default-by.gif' %}" alt = "left slide"/>
```

Hope this will works.

Comment: I had added articles to the template ,but articles is appending to static .. URL /static/articles/img/default-by.gif

Comment: Yes. It will be appended with static url. In your settings file, static url is pointing towards static folder inside you app directory. You have to mention complete inside that directory in order to access these files. Did you check by running 'python manage.py collectstatic'? May it will solve your problem.

Comment: Check this link for documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/